# Echarts wordcloud 2 onclick

Tags: javascript, java, echarts

I am using word-cloud2 with echarts:

Is there any option to add onclick to each word on echarts word-cloud2. My code is in js and is as follows:

```
 var chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var option = {
    tooltip: {},
    series: [ {
        type: 'wordCloud',
        gridSize: 2,
        sizeRange: [12, 50],
        rotationRange: [-90, 90],
        shape: 'apple',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        tooltip: {
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
          },
        drawOutOfBound: true,
        
        data: [
            {
                name: 'Machine Learning',
                value: 10000,
                
            },
           
        ]
    } ]
};

chart.setOption(option);

window.onresize = chart.resize;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after your call to setOption add this:

```
chart.on('click', 'series.wordCloud', function (el) {
    console.log(el);
    // add your custom logic here
});
```